# Private files view only (download, print not allowed)

Tags: php, jquery, node.js

Any body know a solution for Private files view only option (download, print not allowed) ?

consider files type can be PDF/Doc/XLS

I found solution for pdf:

For Private files read only pdf, the file need to create as Images for each page and present those to the user.

PHP with nodejs
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/#contributing

Suggest some source code and ideas...

how scribd and google docs process the document?

Thanks in advance,
SVN

Comment: No matter what you come up with, there will always be a way a user can get a copy of your documents, even if they got a pen and paper and wrote it down...

Comment: There have been various efforts to make "unprintable" documents but they are dependent on special readers. If someone can download it, they can print it. Or alternatively, if someone can see it, they can screencap it.

Comment: my phone has a camera... you cannot stop me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything displayed in a browser (images, fonts, music files, swf movies -and their contents- etc.) can this or that way be grabbed. This is because anything displayed, is actually downloaded to that user's computer. It's a matter of *when* user grabs it and how much technical skills he has.

Your best shot is to make the user agree with some terms (which legally protects you but it won't help you track distribution). You can also assign each user a unique id and embed that in the file itself. So in case you happen to catch a distributed copy, you will know the source. But again, I'm not sure how valuable (in practice) this information can be.

If we were talking about an image, the next best option would be to use a watermark.
For music files, it would be a generic spoken text overlayed on the track, repeating with regular intervals.

So to sum up you can eliminate *basic* users from saving or printing your files, but you can't protect anything **totally** that displays on user's browser, from being saved or printed.